# I can not draw a rectangle using canvas as a child component

Tags: reactjs, canvas, rectangles

I need to draw a rectangle using canvas. Canvas must be in a child component. Like the updateCanvas function. Is it possible to do so?

I tried to draw a rectangle in the parent component and everything works fine, but in this case I need the canvas to be in the child component.

```
// Parent Component

import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Shape from "../../components/Shape";
import "./groupShapes.css";
export default class GroupShapes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // this.state = {
    //   reactanglesOptions: [0, 1, 2]
    // };
    this.canvas = React.createRef();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateCanvas();
  }

  updateCanvas = () => {
    const ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  };

  render() {
    // const { reactanglesOptions } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="groupContainer">
        <Shape ref={this.canvas} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  static propTypes = {
    prop: PropTypes
  };
}

// Child Component
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Shape extends Component {
  render() {
    const { ref } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <canvas ref={ref} width={300} height={300} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Expected Result. Drawn rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react docs it says if you are passing it use ref.current

```
<canvas ref={ref.current} width={300} height={300} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `<Canvas />` to be in child component and update functionality in parent component.
Working [stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-remth2?file=Shape.js)

```
// index.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Shape from './Shape';

class App extends Component {
  updateCanvas = (ctx) => {
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Shape updateCanvas={this.updateCanvas} />
      </div>
    );
  }
    static propTypes = {
    prop: PropTypes
  };
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Shape.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Shape extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = this.refs.canvas
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    this.props.updateCanvas(ctx)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <canvas ref='canvas' width={300} height={300} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!!!